# How to refresh pane background when update date on gauge highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem when I update the gauge chart.
I add some life from my chart using this code:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('my.php', function(data) {    
        $('.container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                    type: 'gauge',
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    width: 170,
                    height: 200,
                    marginTop: 0,
            },
            title: {
                text: 'title',align: 'center',x: 0,y: 8,floating: true
            },
            pane: [{
                startAngle: -120,
                endAngle: 120,
                background: [
                    {
                    backgroundColor: {linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },stops: [[0, '#FFF'],[1, '#333']]},borderWidth: 0,outerRadius: '109%'
                    },
                    {   
                    backgroundColor: {linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },stops: [[0, '#333'],[1, '#FFF']]},borderWidth: 1,outerRadius: '107%'
                    },
                    {
                    backgroundColor: mybackgroundColor(data,100,120),
                    },
                    {   
                    backgroundColor: '#DDD',borderWidth: 0,outerRadius: '105%',innerRadius: '103%'
                    }
                ]
            }],    
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 250,
                minorTickWidth: 1,
                minorTickLength: 10,
                minorTickPosition: 'inside',
                minorTickColor: '#666',
                tickPixelInterval: 30,
                tickWidth: 2,tickLength: 10,
                tickColor: '#666',
                labels: {
                    step: 2,
                    rotation: 'auto'
                },
                title: {
                    text:'km/h',
                    y : 85  
                },
                plotBands: [
                    {
                        from: 0,
                        to: 100,
                        color: '#DDDF0D' /*yellow*/
                    }, 
                    {
                        from: 100,
                        to: 120,
                        color: '#55BF3B' /*green*/
                    }, 
                    {
                        from: 120,
                        to: 250,
                        color: '#DDDF0D' /*yellow*/
                    }, 
                    {
                        from: 30,
                        to: 35,
                        color: '#DF5353' /*red*/
                    }
                ]        
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'speed',
                    data: data,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight:'bold',
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]   

        },


        // Add some life
        function (chart) {
            if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
                setInterval(function () {
                    chart.series[0].color = "#000";
                    var point = chart.series[0].points[0];

                    $.getJSON('mydata.php', function(data) {
                        point.update(data);
                    });
                }, 3000);
            };

        });
    });
});
```

my function mybackgroundColor(data,100,120) define the pane backgroundColor, it depends the value of data.
When I update point ussing this part of code:

```
    // Add some life
    function (chart) {
        if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
            setInterval(function () {
                chart.series[0].color = "#000";
                var point = chart.series[0].points[0];

                $.getJSON('mydata.php', function(data) {
                    point.update(data);
                });
            }, 3000);
        };

    });
```

The wild was updated, but the background didn't.

I try to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
this.chart.plotBackground.attr({
        fill: '#fff'
    })
```

;

Does anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

It's pane background, not a plotBackground. Anyway, in the fact pane background is stored as one of plotBands. So simple you can update it's color:

```
            chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[2].svgElem.attr({
                fill: 'green' 
            });
```

It's `[2]`, because I want to update red plotBand which is third element from background options in a pane.

And some demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/190/